# Exclude values during permutations list creation

Tags: python, permutation

I know that in Python I can easly create a list containing all permutations of a given string, using the `permutations()` function. Now imagine if I wanted to generate only the permutations of the string `"3212323"` that do not contain the string`"33"`. How can I achieve this result ?

Example:

- "3231322"
- "3332122"  <-- I don't want you
- "3213223"
- "3223213"
- "2223313"  <-- I don't want you
- "2322313"
- "2312332"  <-- I don't want you
- ecc...

**Note**: I know that I could generate all the permutations first, and then remove the specified ones from the list, but what I need is to not generate these permutations at all, so discard them while creating the permutations list.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First generate all string with only one `3` then put `3` in positions that are not near another `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with custom filter

```
from itertools import permutations
a="3212323"
def my_filter(temp):
    if '33' not in ''.join(temp):
        return temp
filter(my_filter,(permutations(a)))
```

It's python so you can see the source code and modify it

```
def permutations1(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(n)
    cycles = range(n, n-r, -1)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r]) 
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                temp=tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                if '33' not in ''.join(temp):
                    yield temp
                break
        else:
            return

list((permutations1(a)))
```

Comment: In your first option you can also use [filterfalse(predicate, iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) function from itertools and change the filter function to `return '33' in ''.join(temp)`  
checking if an item exists in the iterable should be faster than checking if it's not in it

Comment: @Oleg Sure you can post it another answer

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generators:

```
original = "3212323"
excluded_substring = '33'
p = (''.join(x) for x in permutations(original))
p = (x for x in p if excluded_substring not in x)

# Or as a one-liner
p = (x for x in (''.join(parts) for parts in permutations(original)) if excluded_substring not in x)
```

All of those are generators, that way you won't have all possible combinations at once in you memory. If you want to have as a list just change the second line (or the outermost in the one-liner) parentheses to square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), they give you what the function is essentially. You can modify this to exclude `'33'`

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                seq = tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])

                # Check if '33' is in sequence
                if '33' not in ''.join(seq):
                    yield seq
                break
        else:
            return
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [_mads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54045821/8219391) first option, you can also use the [filterfalse(predicate, iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) function from itertools:

```
from itertools import permutations, filterfalse

_str = "3212323"

def predicate(iterable):
    return '33' in ''.join(iterable)

filterfalse(predicate, permutations(_str)))
```